# Automatically re-size images to fit screen resolution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I am designing a welcome screen for a desktop application using forms in Visual Studio 2005. I have run into a bit of a problem with the splash image. I'd like it to automatically re-size according to the screen resolution of the user. As it stands I have a source image at a high resolution that I have been shrinking in Photoshop to fit the form design window, but when I build and run the application the image is tiny compared to my screen (1920 x 1080). Right now it is placed inside a panel. I tried messing around with the AutoSize options but that didn't do much.

The question:
How can I set the image to automatically re-size according to the screen resolution of the end user?

Comment: Code, code, code and some more code.  Plus what is your question?

Comment: have you checked the onresize event of the "viewport"? you can bind a function to it (assuming you are going via Windows.Forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picturebox already has this feature. Load the picture and set the property SizeMode.

```
        // correct proportions
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; 
        // or
        // larger, but distorted
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

in code or via the property window and the image will fill the complete picturebox. Set the height/width of the picturebox to scale the image like so:

```
            pictureBox1.Width = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width / 3;
```

Comment: This seems to be doing what I originally intended the image to do. Now I just have to fine tune it, thank you very much for this solution!